# What has changed in iOS 4.2?

Tags: ios

iOS 4.2 has just been released, and I am wondering what exactly has changed? Can I assume that the changes are different for the iPhone, iPod, and iPad?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There were quite a few changes.

The biggest is that this is the first version of iOS 4 for the iPad, which brings multitasking, folders, unified inbox, air print, air play, and more.

This is also the unifying iOS so that the iPad and iPhone and iPod Touch are running the same OS now.

You can find an entire list at http://www.apple.com/ios/

Answer (score 3):

Rene Ritchie, from the TiPb, has been posting really nice walkthroughs for each new iOS version, exploring the new features. I recommend them.

I bundled the walkthroughs for iOS 4.2 for iPhone/iPod and iPad here: http://j.mp/exr6un

Answer (score 1):

- Multitasking on iPad
- Folders on iPad
- AirPrint
- AirPlay
- Find My iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch. (free)

Taken from [iOS 4.2 Software Update](http://www.apple.com/ios/) site.